# Put image width in url jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am using is resrc.it that will resize images for me so that the image is no bigger than I need to be.
Now I want to do is not use the auto javascript method, but put it in the url itsself.

```
<img src="http://app-uk.resrc.it/s={size-of-div}/http://bla.com/theimage.png" />
```

I want to use jquery to measure the size of the div the image and print it in the URL whhat the current size of wrapped div is.

How can I put the width into a value of URL? I can using plain Javascript or Jquery, if no JS method exists.

After that it will crop the image and give me back a better suitable image.

Comment: What have you tried?  You should at least show what you have tried, and not expect people to just give you the answer, especially given the fact that you have a generated username, and low amount of reputation.

Comment: I dont know why my user is generated. I have tried some php methods and i dont know jQuery's formatting well enough to make my own functions. i could use the width() method but then i have to wait for jQuery to load, was just hoping someone knew what to do or could point me to an example

Comment: You'd probably have to wait for the DOM to load anyway, in this case use a $(document).ready(function(){..});  This way, you guarantee the document is done loading, then get the dimensions of the div through .width();

Comment: But how would i insert that into the url? The formatting is what i cannot understanrd

Comment: Some pseudocode: var imgUrl = startOfUrl + width() + endOfUrl; var imgTag = $('<img>'); imgTag.attr('src', imgUrl); addImageToDom()

Answer (score 1):

You need find images and get parent width. Try this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("img[src*='size-of-div']").each(function(){
     var width = this.parentNode.offsetWidth;//get parent width
      this.src = this.src.replace("{size-of-div}",width)//change src string
    })
})
```

Comment: Is there any way i can put this in the url itsself?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for this: http://api.jquery.com/width/